# Why SavedInstanceState is not null in activity after changing device language while the app is in background?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-savedstate

I created a new activity for my app and implemented a BroadcastReceiver to handle the device language changing and when the user put the app in background and change the language, the activity should be recreated. I call this method in onCreate in my activity and I check if savedInstanceState is null before calling the languageReceiver(), but when I change the language, the savedInstanceState is not null and the method is not called...

**The setupLangReceiver() method**

```
private fun setupLangReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver? {
    if (mLangReceiver == null) {
        mLangReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                recreateActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        registerReceiver(mLangReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED))
    }
    return mLangReceiver
}
```

**The recreateActivity() method**

```
 private fun recreateActivity(intent: Intent) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
    finish()
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    startActivity(intent)
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
}
```

**SetupLangReceiver method calling**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prb_module)
    ThemeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setupLangReceiver()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After u change the system langugae, ur app can be recreate by the system. And the system saves the activity's sate automatically. So u can ovveride the method `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: And what should I do inside that method? Can you give me an example of code? Thanks.

Comment: If you change the sys language, the activity will be killed by the system. So your activity will save the state in the method `onSaveInstanceState`, you can check the docs here (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))